# Materialize get data info from trigger

Tags: jquery, materialize

Is there a way to transmit to the modal div some data from the trigger button?

Here my code.

```
<button data-id="123" class="modal-trigger" href="#info-modal">OPEN 123</button>
<button data-id="456" class="modal-trigger" href="#info-modal">OPEN 456</button>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>My Modal</h4>
        <p>this info arrives from the data-id attribute on the trigger.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">CLOSE</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        $(".modal").modal({
            onOpenStart: function(){
                // changes the p content inside .modal-content from the data-id triggered button.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add click listener to your buttons and then when button is clicked you can use `this` reference to grab value of `data-id` attribute from button that is clicked and then put that value inside modal using `.html()` method.

Here is a working [example](https://jsbin.com/sodobitaqi/2/edit?html,output) and your modified code:

```
<button data-id="123" class="modal-trigger" href="#info-modal">OPEN 123</button>
<button data-id="456" class="modal-trigger" href="#info-modal">OPEN 456</button>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>My Modal</h4>
        <p>this info arrives from the data-id attribute on the trigger.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">CLOSE</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Have fun using Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function($) {
    $(".modal-trigger").click(function(){
          var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
          $("#modal .modal-content p").html(data_id);
          $('#modal').modal('show');
    });
        
    });
</script>
```